# Get current action in extbase

Tags: extbase, typo3-8.x

TYPO3 v8

I have created a custom Validator class in my extbase project.

I call the validator on the model:

```
* @validate ME\MyProject\Domain\Validator\MyCustomValidator
```

I need to check/test what the current Action is inside the validator class.

How do I find this out?

Thanks again T3 community